# Application dispatcher invoke freezes the application

Tags: wpf, multithreading, messagebox, dispatcher

I am having problem with the application freezing. Let me explain my scenario, I have a service which does an async call to a database to get a list of items, It is run by a task. Inside this task I have a try catch block, so it looks like this

```
public Task<List<T>> ComboListAsync(int? id = null, EnumDTO dto = EnumDTO.Default)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (var context = new ContextService())
            {
                try
                {
                    return GetComboList(id, dto, context);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Handler.DatabaseConnectionException();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Then it throws an exception as GetComboList its just this (for the moment)

```
    protected virtual List<T> GetComboList(int? id, EnumDTO dto, ContextService context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

So the call catches the exception and goes inside here

```
    public void Show(string message)
    {
        Message = message;
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            dialogView = new DialogView() {DataContext = this, Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow};
            dialogView.ShowDialog();
        });
    }
```

Now the Dispatcher freezes the app, I tried to change it to use begin invoke, it does the same. Without the dispatcher I get an error message that the calling thread is not a STA. I simply want to display my message in a dialog window, that there was a problem connecting to a database. Can anyone help?
I looked online and there is many threads about dispatcher, but none actually show a solution that will fix my issue.

Thank you

**EDIT**
Code which calls the ComboListAsync

```
    protected override void RetrieveRelatedActiveLists()
    {
        MyCollection = service.ComboListAsync().Result;
    }
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the `Show()` method is it being hit? What about inside the Invoke()? Also, can you post the code that calls `ComboListAsnyc()` and `Show()`?

Comment: must be part of whatever calls your methods above, it worked fine for me

Comment: @AndrewStephens is hit the show and it gets to line Application.Current.Dispatcher at this point it goes back to the UI and it freezes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a deadlock because of the calling code is using the `.Result`.

Using `service.ComboListAsync().Result` makes the UI thread await for this method to return, when you call `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke` from within it you are sending a message to the UI thread that is awaiting the return of method itself.

You must **await** the method `service.ComboListAsync()` like this:

```
  protected override async void RetrieveRelatedActiveLists()
  {
      MyCollection = await service.ComboListAsync();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves it. What I don't understand is why it actually happens, I thought that Results will actually call await.

Comment: Well it don't, Result blocks the thread until the the function returns, think of it as sync awaiting. The await keyword on the other hand let the thread to run and set a "bookmark", when the method returns it continues from the bookmarked point. It is the async awaiting. Tecnically it is more complicated than that. Grab a coffee and start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I'll definitely read it. There is one thing about the await I don't like, it continues to run the code and it does not freeze, however MyCollection is accessed right away after this method and it throws null reference exception, while with results, it would go back to UI display some animation and when its ready continue. So I guess the code which consumes MyCollection also needs to be async, but then the code that consumes that as well, so at the end everything would have to be async, as one method relies on the other.

Comment: Yep, async/await go down the chain all the way. But if you think about, it makes sense( why would you like to freeze UI ). An option is to use a Task continuation like: service.ComboListAsync().ContinueWith( /* UpdateUI here */ ) but I think it is very uglyish more details here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).)... There is another approach, but that would change your code completely and it is a completely new world. It is named RxFramework (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your reply again, I guess I just need to investigate it much further than I thought initially :)